# External resource not being loaded by AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Using Angular and Phonegap, I'm trying to load a video that is on a remote server but came across an issue. In my JSON, the URL is entered as a plain HTTP URL.

```
"src" : "http://www.somesite.com/myvideo.mp4"
```

My video template

```
 <video controls poster="img/poster.png">
       <source ng-src="{{object.src}}" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
```

All my other data gets loaded but when I look my console, I get this error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{object.src}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL
```

I tried in adding `$compileProvider` in my config set up but it did not resolve my issue.

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
```

I saw [**this post about cross domain issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640920/load-image-data-into-angularjs)s but I'm not sure how to resolve this or what direction I should go in. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you also post your corodva's ```config.xml``` file?

Comment: Right now I'm still testing in the browser so I haven't even started my phonegap debugging.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }

  $scope.movie = {src:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE", title:"Egghead.io AngularJS Binding"};
});
```

Then in an iframe:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
        ng-src="{{trustSrc(movie.src)}}" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tYq22VjwB10WmytQO9Pb?p=preview

Comment: Is this possible without an iFrame?  I need to embed a video where the session info determines whether or not the consumer is allowed to see the video. The session information is not carried through the iFrame.

Comment: nice, if you can use iframe

Answer (score 271):

Another simple solution is to create a filter:

```
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
}]);
```

Then specify the filter in `ng-src`:

```
<video controls poster="img/poster.png">
       <source ng-src="{{object.src | trusted}}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Best answer, more angular spirit and it worked where the others solutions didn't for some reasons. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 77):

## Whitelist the resource with $sceDelegateProvider

This is caused by a new security policy put in place in Angular 1.2. It makes XSS harder by preventing a hacker from dialling out (i.e. making a request to a foreign URL, potentially containing a payload).

To get around it properly you need to whitelist the domains you want to allow, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
    'http://srv*.assets.example.com/**'
  ]);

  // The blacklist overrides the whitelist so the open redirect here is blocked.
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
    'http://myapp.example.com/clickThru**'
  ]);
});
```

This example is lifted from the documentation which you can read here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider

Be sure to include ngSanitize in your app to make this work.

### Disabling the feature

If you want to turn off this useful feature, and you're sure your data is secure, you can simply allow **, like so:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['**']);
});
```

Comment: Note: if `resourceUrlWhitelist` somehow doesn't work for you, check if you don't have double slash after domain name (easy for this to happen when concatenating stuff from variables and they both have slashes)

Comment: This is a cleaner, global and secure way to go around this issue.

Comment: "Dialing out" is not a great term to use for someone trying to understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Ringo - I have added a comment to clarify.

Answer (score 21):

Had the same issue here. I needed to bind to Youtube links. What worked for me, as **a global solution**, was to add the following to my config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {

    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?youtube\.com/.+$')]);

}]);
```

Adding **'self'** in there is important - otherwise will fail to bind to any URL. From the [angular docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/%24sce)

> 'self' -  The special string, 'self', can be used to match against all
>   URLs of the same domain as the application document using the same
>   protocol.

With that in place, I'm now able to bind directly to any Youtube link.

You'll obviously have to customise the regex to your needs. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

The best and easy solution for solving this issue is pass your data from this function in controller.

```
$scope.trustSrcurl = function(data) 
{
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data);
}
```

In html page

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" ng-src="{{trustSrcurl(video.src)}}" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem using Videogular. I was getting the following when using ng-src:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{url}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy
```

I fixed the problem by writing a basic directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('dynamicUrl', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.attr('src', scope.content.fullUrl);
  }
};
});
```

The html:

```
 <div videogular vg-width="200" vg-height="300" vg-theme="config.theme">
    <video class='videoPlayer' controls preload='none'>
          <source dynamic-url src='' type='{{ content.mimeType }}'>
    </video>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is looking for a TypeScript solution:

**.ts file (change variables where applicable):**

```
module App.Filters {

    export class trustedResource {

        static $inject:string[] = ['$sce'];

        static filter($sce:ng.ISCEService) {
            return (value) => {
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value)
            };
        }
    }
}
filters.filter('trustedResource', App.Filters.trusted.filter);
```

**Html:**

```
<video controls ng-if="HeaderVideoUrl != null">
  <source ng-src="{{HeaderVideoUrl | trustedResource}}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, your problem seems to be related to *interpolation* (typically your expression `{{}}`), not to a cross-domain issue. Basically `ng-src="{{object.src}}"` sucks.

`ng-src` was designed with `img` tag in mind IMO. It might not be appropriate for `<source>`. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc

If you declare `<source src="somesite.com/myvideo.mp4"; type="video/mp4"/>`, it will be working, right? (note that I remove `ng-src` in favor of `src`) If not it must be fixed first.

Then ensure that `{{object.src}}` returns the expected value (**outside** of `<video>`):

```
<span>{{object.src}}</span>
<video>...</video>
```

If it returns the expected value, the following statement should be working:

```
<source src="{{object.src}}"; type="video/mp4"/> //src instead of ng-src
```

Comment: Using just src and hard coding the url, everything work as I want. As soon as I use {{object.src}} though the src attribute isn't even passed thought. I went ahead and even remove the source tag and put the src inline with the video tag but still nothing

Comment: I mean are you sure that {{object.src}} returns a value? It might return undefined.

Comment: {{object.src}} is returning a value. Tested it by using a <p></p> and a <a></a>

Comment: There is another alternative: using a directive.

Comment: Probably going to have to, already found this and it looks pretty good. http://www.videogular.com/#/. Thanks for the help

Comment: So I was able to get the video to load without the use of directives by setting $sceProvider.enabled(false); and was able to load the video in safari, android, and ios but not chrome oddly enough. So I think the issue was with chrome's security settings.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `ng-src` being broken (it isn't broken). It has to do with AngularJS's security policy: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in **tests**, the directive `templateUrl` wasn't trusted, but only for the spec, so I added the template directory:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.templates'));
```

My main directory is `app`.