# Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hy all i have an error:
Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy

i use angularjs + rails

this is a template:

I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.

post.source is https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-xaf1/v/t42.1790-2/1038699_10202931983969896_170894113_n.mp4

this my app conf angularjs:

$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        '....',
        '....',
        '....',
        '....',
        'https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-xaf1/v/t42.1790-2/1038699_10202931983969896_170894113_n.mp4'
    ]);

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
    'http://myapp.example.com/clickThru**']);
```

it's possible disabled controll angular URL ??
thanks

Comment: This is a new security policy introduced in 1.2. You need to whitelist the domain. You can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28501975/687677

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs