# $sce:itype Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: resourceUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, sails.js, ngsanitize

I want to play songs stored in my sails server. Path is `http://localhost:4000/images/123.mp3`.

In front end, i'm using ng-repeat to list that songs from server.

```
 <div ng-repeat="tones in ringTones track by $index">
      <div>
        <i ng-show="playpause" class="fa fa-play-circle"   ng-click="playpause=!playpause" onclick="plays(event);"><audio id="audio_{{$index}}" ng-src="tones.tonePath"></audio></i> 
        <i ng-show="!playpause" class="fa fa-pause"   ng-click="playpause=!playpause" onclick="stop(event);"></i></div>

</div>
```

This audio source cause external resource problem

```
<audio ng-src="tones.tonePath"></audio>
```

in angular controller, i'm using $sce

```
$http.get("http://localhost:4000/songs/find").success(function(data){
        $rootScope.ringTones=data;
        $rootScope.ringTones.push($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data[0]));
 }).error(function(data){
                    console.log('ERROR');
 });
```

Error is :

```
Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a 
    content requiring a string: Context: resourceUrl
```

Without using $sce that cause

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: tones.tonePath
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL
```

This is my JSON from server

```
 [{
    "toneName": "2",
    "aboutTone": "2",
    "duration": 2,
    "tonePath": "http://localhost:4000/images/234.mp3",
    "createdAt": "2015-08-03T15:40:58.227Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-03T15:40:58.227Z",
    "id": "55bf8b8a77efb94b32b158c0"
  },
  {
    "toneName": "3",
    "aboutTone": "3",
    "duration": 3,
    "tonePath": "http://localhost:4000/images/123.mp3",
    "createdAt": "2015-08-03T15:45:16.120Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-03T15:45:16.120Z",
    "id": "55bf8c8c77efb94b32b158c1"
  }
]
```

Then how to play external mp3 in my ng-repeat. Help me.

Comment: What is the data coming back from the server?

Comment: "http://localhost:4000/images/123.mp3", "http://localhost:4000/images/234.mp3" like this.

Comment: It needs to be parsed into an array.` data.split(',')[0] `

Comment: why need split data? please explain me

Comment: The data is coming back as one big string, so if you split the string into an array at each comma then you have the data as an array and you can choose the first, last, nth index of that array.

Comment: i'm using above JSON type. Not processing string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution :
[External resource not being loaded by AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs)

```
  app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function(url) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        };
    }]);
```

Then specify the filter in ng-src:

```
   <audio 
        ng-src="{{tones.tonePath | trusted}}" />
    </audio>
```

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

```
//first Take data from api 

$scope.Data= JSLINQ(data.Data).Select(function (Item) { return Item; })                    

//Map data as trustable to scope
$scope.Data.items.map(function (i) {
                     i.Header1 = $sce.trustAsHtml(i.Header1);     
                 });

//UI bind modal data

<p ng-bind-html="x1.Header1 " ng-show="x1.Header1 != null"></p>
```