# Reading external url from json file using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

How can I fetch /display external media content from URL stored in json file using angular js?

JSON

```
"media": [
        {
          "title": "Example_1",
          "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
        },
        …….
]
```

Controller

```
controller('Controller', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('myjson.json').success(function (data){

        $scope.medianew = data.media;

     });
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat = "md in medianew">                           
      <video ng-src="{{md.url}}" width="240" controls></video>
</div>
```

I am not able to display media from external sources. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Getting Error: $interpolate:interr
Interpolation Error

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=http:%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fhtml%2Fmov_bbb.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is somewhat similar to this [one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs)

You need to use `$sce` service from angular. I made a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HFRqTRXtnKnp10sxXgOn?p=preview) to solve your problem.

```
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {

  $http.get('myjson.json').success(function (data){
    $scope.medianew = data.media.map(function (m) {
      m.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(m.url);
      return m;
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'll need to parse the content of the `json` file as `json` content.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    // parse the string content as json
    $scope.mediaNew = JSON.parse('[{"title":"Example_1","url":"http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"}]');
    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       // trust an insecure url
       return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    };
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat = "md in mediaNew">    
     <h1>
        {{md.title}}
     </h1>
     <video ng-src="{{ trustSrc(md.url) }}" width="240" controls></video>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Working demo -  https://jsfiddle.net/aghosh08/c2d8pwr7/

Comment: well the parsing actually works, but angular is blocking loading content from an insecure url for