# angular interpolate:interr error when adding url from variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a dynamic id to a youtube url like this:

```
<iframe width="460px" height="415px" ng-src="{{post.youtube_id}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is one of the urls I am trying to to put in the src: https://www.youtube.com/embed/C-IiiFvfdVo

When I do this I get the following error:

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bpost.youtube_id%7D%7D&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24sce%3Ainsecurl%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24sce%2Finsecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fembed%252FozXJ0QrEj2Y
>
> angular.min.js:118 Error: [$interpolate:interr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bpost.youtube…ecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fembed%252FozXJ0QrEj2Y
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:6:412
>       at Function.Ka.interr (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:210:135)
>       at J (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:104:438)
>       at Array. (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:128:471)
>       at S.exp (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:106:51)
>       at Object.pre (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:79:374)
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:16:71
>       at la (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:81:90)
>       at p (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:66:149)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:118(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:90J @ angular.min.js:104(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:128S.exp @ angular.min.js:106pre @
>   angular.min.js:79(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:16la @
>   angular.min.js:81p @ angular.min.js:66g @ angular.min.js:58g @
>   angular.min.js:58g @ angular.min.js:58g @ angular.min.js:58(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.min.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:63d
>   @ angular.min.js:59m @ angular.min.js:64(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:305q @ angular.min.js:7(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:305$digest @ angular.min.js:143$apply @
>   angular.min.js:146l @ angular.min.js:97J @ angular.min.js:102t.onload
>   @ angular.min.js:103 angular.min.js:118 Error: [$interpolate:interr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bpost.youtube…ecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fembed%252FozXJ0QrEj2Y
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:6:412
>       at Function.Ka.interr (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:210:135)
>       at J (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:104:438)
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:128:471
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:127:103
>       at m.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:143:43)
>       at m.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:146:113)
>       at l (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:97:322)
>       at J (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/common/angular/js/angular.min.js:102:34)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:118(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:90J @ angular.min.js:104(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:128(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:127$digest @
>   angular.min.js:143$apply @ angular.min.js:146l @ angular.min.js:97J @
>   angular.min.js:102t.onload @ angular.min.js:103

**How can I add this?**

Comment: use `ng-src`. if that doesn't work, then post your code for further assistance.

Comment: Can you provide the full error link, without the "..." part? What is the context for your HTML template, ie where are you trying to use it?

Comment: Nope, they've still got the "..." bits. If you click the error link you can then copy the full URL and paste it into your question. Also, use the unminified version of `angular.js` while developing; the error messages are more verbose

Comment: Much better! So the *real* error is https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=https:%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FozXJ0QrEj2Y

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer here: [External resource not being loaded by AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs)

```
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
   return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl;
}]);
```

Then specify the filter in ng-src:

```
<video controls poster="img/poster.png">
       <source ng-src="{{object.src | trusted}}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```