# AngularJS errors: Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I'm currently following a tutorial in AngularJS. This is the code in my controllers.js file.

```
'use strict';

angular.module ( 'F1FeederApp.controllers' , []                                     )
.controller    ( 'driversController'       , function ( $scope , ergastAPIservice ) {

    $scope.nameFilter = null;
    $scope.driversList = [];

    ergastAPIservice.getDrivers ().success ( function ( response ) {
        $scope.driversList = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists [ 0 ].DriverStandings;
    });
});
```

I'm getting the following errors:

1) Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.

2) TypeError: ergastAPIservice.getDrivers(...).success is not a function

I'm not particularly sure at all what could be causing these errors, I'm very new to Angular. The only possible differences I've seen between mine and other examples is that in this block of code: ( services.js )

```
'use strict';

angular.module ( 'F1FeederApp.services' , []                 )
.factory       ( 'ergastAPIservice'     , function ( $http ) {

    var ergastAPI = {};

    ergastAPI.getDrivers = function () {
        return $http ({
            method : 'JSONP' ,
            url    : 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    };

    return ergastAPI;
});
```

The differences I've noticed are that in mine there is a semi-colon at the end of the getDrivers function and that I have the `use strict` statement at the top of the file as well. However, grunt refuses to run the application without both of those lines, so I don't think that could be the issue.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Issue #1** :

The **url** you are trying to request from your app is not safe
    according to the AngularJS [**sceDelegatePolicy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). To resolve it, you need
    to whitelist the url in your app using `resourceUrlWhitelist` method
    in  **[$sceDelegateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider)** as shown below :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {  
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain. **.
    'http://ergast.com/**'
  ]);
```

For a clear explanation and above example are from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs)**

**Issue #2:**

The issue with the error `TypeError: ergastAPIservice.getDrivers(...).success is not a function` could be due to the AngularJS version that you are using. The legacy **`.success/.error` methods are now deprecated in the latest AngularJs version 1.6**. Here is the **[Deprecation notice](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)** If you are using the latest AngularJs, that could be the reason, otherwise, we need more information to debug the issue.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}

and your html should have {{trustSrc(myUrl)}} instead of {{myUrl}}
```

Comment: Where is `$sce` defined and what is it a reference to?

Comment: @lance.dolan it's a https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce - add it to the function() parameters when you create your controller and to the array assigned to controller.$inject