# Angularjs filter to sanitize data is throwing non-string value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a html data coming from a server as a string that i wanted to display on the client side,So using a below filter resolve my problem but i also see error in console that i pasted in question.
How can i correct `filter` implementation ?

Data varies and changed its not just html every time it renders it could be plain string as well.

filter.js

```
angular.module('App').filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function(url) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        };
    }]);
```

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages | filter:searchStr">
    <td>{{item.filename}}</td>
    <td class="serverResults" ng-bind-html="item.value | highlight:searchStr| trusted">{{item.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Error

```
Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: resourceUrl
```

Comment: What are the values can take `url`? Did you try `$sce.trustAsHtml(url);`?

Comment: I hope you checked this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs