# Error while loading external resources using AngularJS JSONP

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, jsonp

Im really confused on how to load external resource with $http.jsonp. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
{{myData}}
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
var url = "https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero";
  $http.jsonp(url).then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And i got error like this:

> Error: [$sce:insecurl]

Whats wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at these two links. 1. Explains why this happens[https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl] 2. A solution[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292114/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine by updating your angular version from `1.6.4` to  `1.2.6`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
var url = "https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero";
  $http.jsonp(url).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
      $scope.myData = response.data;
      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"></div>
```