# Link to video in DynamoDB and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-dynamodb

I have some videos located in an S3 bucket and Im referencing their links in a DynamoDB table along with some other relevant info (all as items). I have created a simple AngularJS app that retrieves the items from the Dynamo table via API Gateway and Lamdba and simply displays the info in a controller. Here is the body of my index.html:

```
<body>
      <div class="row" ng-controller="content">
        <div class="col-8">
            <p><b>{{content['course-title']}}</b></p>
            <p>{{content['course-video']}}</p>
            <p>The ID is {{content['course-content']}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

and here is my .js for the single controller:

```
.controller('content', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api link').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.content = response.data.body[0];
            console.log(response)
        });
});
```

As you can see I am returning a json array in the response and referencing each element by name in the controller itself.

Everything is working fine with the process except for the video.

**Here is my question:**

One of the table items is a link to a video in S3 as follows:

https://xyz-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4

How/what do I need to do to embed the video properly so it will display? It is referenced by:

```
<p>{{content['course-video']}}</p>
```

Obviously, right now just the link is being returned. How do I incorporate it properly as a video source?

---

I tried using `<video>` element and I got the following error:

> [$interpolate:interr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr) Interpolation Error.

I had to use `ng-src`, but still got the error

Comment: Did you try using a  [`<video>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)?

Comment: Yes, I have and I got the following error: $interpolate:interr
Interpolation Error. I had to use ng-src, but still got the error.

Comment: The interpolation failed because of some exception. It would be helpful to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60355991/edit) the question to include all of the error message.

Comment: @georgeawg yes, thanks for doing that for me and Ill remember that next time - been a little while since Ive been super active here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `video` tag:

```
<p><video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src={{content['course-video']}} type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></p>
```

Comment: Thanks - I had already tried such and got the following error when I did: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error

Comment: you also need to follow this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577208/290036

Comment: How does that solution work with dynamic content? I need the src to be dynamic. Thank you for you help.